# Can I reduce the number of containers and (seemingly) redundant loops when querying parents and grandparents?

Tags: apex, bulkification, performance

**tl;dr** - I'm retrieving fields on an object, the object's parent, and the parent's parent in a trigger - is there any way to make my code use less than 5 containers and remain bulkified?

---

I have an object called Client_Sat_Survey__c that is a child of Opportunity. There's a update trigger on Client_Sat_Survey__c that fires an email to three people:

1. A Contact stored on Client_Sat_Survey__c itself (lookup)
2. The Account Executive, a field on the parent Opportunity (lookup to User)
3. The Client Partner, a field on the Account, which is the parent of the Opportunity (so the grandparent of the Client_Sat_Survey, if you will - also a lookup to User)

---

Because of the hierarchical nature of these users (each one stored on a different object), the code I wrote to email them seems a bit verbose. I bulkified it, but am using (what seems to be) an unnecessarily large number of containers and repetitive loops. I realize the performance impact of allocating these containers and executing these loops is relatively negligible, **but I would still like to learn from anyone more experienced that sees ways I can reduce the verbosity.**

```
// Handler for all Apex triggers on Client_Sat_Survey__c
// Brian Mansfield, 7-1-2015

public class ClientSatSurveyTriggerHandler {

  public static void handleBeforeUpdate(List<Client_Sat_Survey__c> newRecs) {

    // We have to use so many containers here because we're working from the Client_Sat_Survey level,
    // which is the child of Opportunity. The requirement is to CC the Account Executive, which is stored
    // on the Opportunity (parent of survey), and the Client Partner, which is on the Account, so we have 
    // to traverse several levels of SOQL...

    Map<ID, String> oppToAccountExecEmailMap = new Map<ID, String>();
    Map<ID, String> accountToEmailHelperMap = new Map<ID, String>();
    Map<ID, String> oppToClientPartnerEmailMap = new Map<ID, String>();
    Set<ID> accountIDs = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> oppIDs = new Set<ID>();

    // store the Opportunity IDs of the parents of each survey
    for (Client_Sat_Survey__c c : newRecs) {
        oppIDs.add(c.Opportunity__c);
    }

    // retrieve each parent Opportunity of the surveys in the trigger context:
    List<Opportunity> opps = [
        SELECT Id, Account_Executive__r.id, Account_Executive__c, AccountId, Account_Executive__r.email
        FROM Opportunity 
        WHERE Id IN :oppIDs];

    // store the Account IDs for each opportunity so that we can retrieve the Client Partner for each Account
    for (Opportunity oPerSurvey : opps) {
        accountIDs.add(oPerSurvey.AccountId);
    }

    // retrieve the parent Accounts of the parent Opportunities of the survey
    List<Account> accounts = [
        SELECT Id, Client_Partner__r.id, Client_Partner__c, Client_Partner__r.email
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :accountIDs];

    // store the client partner email, by Account ID key
    for (Account a : accounts) {
        accountToEmailHelperMap.put(a.id, a.Client_Partner__r.email);
    }

    // populate both the contact maps, both keys are Opportunity ID
    for (Opportunity o : opps) {
        oppToAccountExecEmailMap.put(o.id, o.Account_Executive__r.Email);
        oppToClientPartnerEmailMap.put(o.id, accountToEmailHelperMap.get(o.AccountId));
    }

    // Create instance of emails to send 
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> surveyMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for (Client_Sat_Survey__c c : newRecs) {
        // Create Messaging.SingleEmailMessage, set body, etc here
        mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Survey_Contact__c);
        List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
        ccTo.add(oppToAccountExecEmailMap.get(c.Opportunity__r.id));
        ccTo.add(oppToClientPartnerEmailMap.get(c.Opportunity__r.id));
        mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
        surveyMails.add(mail);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(surveyMails);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I use 5 containers and 4 loops simply to populate the containers - before the actual logic is even executed.

Comment: As a first step, why not create a formula field on the Client_Sat_Survey__c to pull in the Opportunity__r.AccountID And the Opportunity__r.Account.Client_Partner__r.email and any other field you may need in the trigger context. Seems it would reduce A LOT of the code

Comment: Management wants to avoid adding fields if possible. Ideally, I would have all the recipients stored on Client_Sat_Survey__c

Comment: Tradeoff between performance and 2 or 3 formula fields.....I say it is time to have a talk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments on formula fields, in lieu of that try:

Answer pending code rewrite based on no formula fields

As a start:

```
// Handler for all Apex triggers on Client_Sat_Survey__c
// Brian Mansfield, 7-1-2015

    public class ClientSatSurveyTriggerHandler {

      public static void handleBeforeUpdate(List<Client_Sat_Survey__c> newRecs) {


        //I have a list for the values, but you should either change it to a single value or change the email code to work with a list depending on your data model
        Map<id,Client_Sat_Survey__c[]> oppToCS = New Map<ID,Client_Sat_Survey__c[]{};

        //Get a list with all the required fields
        for(Client_Sat_Survey__c survey : [Select Opportunity__c, 
                                            Opportunity__r.AccountID, 
                                            Opportunity__r.Account.Account_Executive__c,
                                            Opportunity__r.Account.Account_Executive__r.email,
                                            Opportunity__r.Account.Client_Partner__r.id, 
                                            Opportunity__r.Account.Client_Partner__c, 
                                            Opportunity__r.Account.Client_Partner__r.email]){

                if(!oppToCS.containsKey(survey.Opportunity__c))
                    oppToCS.put(survey.Opportunity__c,New Client_Sat_Survey__c[]{});

                oppToCS.get(survey.Opportunity__c).add(survey);

        }


        // Create instance of emails to send 
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> surveyMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for (Client_Sat_Survey__c c : newRecs) {
                // Create Messaging.SingleEmailMessage, set body, etc here
                mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Survey_Contact__c);
                List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
                ccTo.add(oppToCS.get(c.Opportunity__c)[0].Opportunity__r.Account_Executive__r.Email);
                ccTo.add(oppToCS.get(c.Opportunity__c)[0].Opportunity__r.Account.Client_Partner__r.email);

                mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
                surveyMails.add(mail);
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(surveyMails);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I was under the impression you couldn't traverse more than one level of relationship in a query...so I thought something like `SELECT Opportunity__r.Account.Client_Partner__r.email FROM Client_Sat_Survey__c` wouldn't even compile. For the last two years I've always been using separate queries for cases like this.......this is exactly why I asked, thank you Eric

Comment: @BrianMansfield - If your model does not require the logic for a list, etc, simplify it to techbusinessmans answer below if it is a one to one email per client survey

Comment: @BrianMansfield - I believe the limit is 5 levels, unless it has changed

Answer (score 3):

I would probably reduce to something similar to this:

```
List<Client_Sat_Survey__c> cssList = [SELECT Id, Survey_Contact__c
                                        Opportunit__r.Id, Opportunit__r.Account_Executive__r.id, Opportunit__r.Account_Executive__c, 
                                        Opportunit__r.AccountId, Opportunit__r.Account_Executive__r.email, AccountId, 
                                        Opportunit__r.Account.Client_Partner__r.id, Opportunit__r.Account.Client_Partner__c, 
                                        Opportunit__r.Account.Client_Partner__r.email
                                      FROM Client_Sat_Survey__c WHERE Id IN :newRecs];

for(Client_Sat_Survey__c css : cssList)
{
    mail.setTargetObjectId(css.Survey_Contact__c);
    List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
    ccTo.add(css.Opportunity__r.Account_Executive__r.Email);
    ccTo.add(css.Opportunity__r.Client_Partner__r.Email));
    mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
    surveyMails.add(mail);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, and here I thought that putting up the pending code rewrite in my answer would give me time to rewrite it before someone posted the (almost exact) same thing and waste my time.....lol (Note: tone of voice here is laughing, not critical)

Comment: We both win :) it's always nice to get validation ;)